# Concurrency with the new Worker Class in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript, concurrency, worker

Is it possible to render a displayobject (spark component) in a actionscript Worker and then add it to the DisplayList of the MainThread. I have seen on Adobe TV something about an option Worker.view to render offscreen. But i can't find it in the Worker Class of the Flash.system package. i'm also not sure off this option is only to render and place BitmapData on screen.